# How to handle data conflicts firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Recently I'm trying to use firebase realtime database to synchronize data, our app all the data in sqlite to store, we hope to continue to store data in sqlite, and can be used firebase real-time synchronization of data in different devices, how should I handle data conflicts from different devices. Thanks for helping

Comment: It's typically best to design your data model so that it prevents conflicts. But unless you have a specific example in mind, this is an incredibly broad topic that can not easily covered in Stack Overflow's Q&A format.